# How to start gscam in groovy/hydro?

Tags: ros-groovy, gscam, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

There seems to be conflicting info about how to start and use gscam. http://wiki.ros.org/gscam states to go to the bin/ directory but http://answers.ros.org/question/91676/how-to-install-gscam/ mentions something entirely different. Also, when trying, I find that ~/.ros/camera_info doesn't exist. Shouldn't this be installed with gscam ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153631/how-to-start-gscam-in-groovy/hydro-?/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-04-16**:
Hi,
it doesn't matter if you don't have your bin or the camera_info folder. Did you tried something and get errors?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-04-16**:
Yes, I did. I exported GSCAM_CONFIG, started  "rosrun gscam gscam". Got the messages that it can't open the camera calibration file and that camera.yaml isn't found. It does start the stream but "rostopic list" doesn't show any /gscam topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have that warning because you didn't calibrate your camera. It's not an error, it's just a warning so you can still run your gscam. You won't have any /gscam topics, but something like /camera/camerainfo /camera/image_raw. Do you have something like that?

---

Originally posted by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) with karma: 42 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-04-16**:
I did have those topics, now it's failing for some reason so have to figure out why.

Ok, had wrong framerate. So have those topics again.

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-04-16**:
So your gscam is running. Do you have other problems?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-04-16**:
OK, what's wrong with "rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw" that I get "Illegal instruction (core dumped)" ?

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-04-16**:
what did you put in your GSCAM_CONFIG? make sure your device is the good one

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-04-16**:
If you mean like device=/dev/video0, yes it is. The whole GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=25/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace"

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-04-17**:
try GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace"

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-04-17**:
same result

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-04-19**:
OK, found out why it gives Illegal instruction. It seems that the AMD cpu can't handle (part of) rosrun.